# When i open my drive in linux it can't open ,what i do

Tags: unity

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/rajeev/A480692B80690560: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o 
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" 
"/dev/sda2" "/media/rajeev/A480692B80690560"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated,
 refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. 
Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with
 the 'ro' mount option.
```

Answer (score 0):

one solution could be to boot to windows OS and then shut it down properly.  restart your pc, boot into ubuntu and try to access windows drives.

i have had this situation once and following above procedure solved the problem